# Which is correct for polynomial? The number of degrees or the number of exponents?

Tags: polynomials

I'm sorry for asking a petty question.
But, I think here is the best place to ask.

If we have a polynomial $a(x)$ of degree $k-1$

$a(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_i x^i$

I know we can say that the degree of $a(x)$ is $k-1$ since degree refers to the highest number of exponents.

Can we say that the number of exponents is $k$?

Comment: `degree refers to the highest number of exponents` Degree refers to the highest power of $x$. Not sure what you mean by "*number of exponents*", for example $x^n+1$ has degree $n$ but only two terms.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your comment! Yeah I think power is correct for the definition of degree. So for polynomial, we do not usually use the term "exponent"?

Comment: Yes, you can use exponent in the usual sense: the $n^{th}$ power of $x$ is $x^n$ and its exponent is $n$. What's not clear, however, is what you mean by "*number of exponents*".

Comment: @dxiv "highest number of exponents", this is my pitfall. It should be "highest power of x." Or, "highest exponent"?

Comment: By the way, does "polynomial exponent" make any sense in general?

Comment: Both work, though "*highest power of x*" is more common in my experience. "*Polynomial exponent*" doesn't make sense, unless maybe you raise the entire polynomial to some power, and even in that case you need to word it carefully in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81776/discussion-between-mallea-and-dxiv).

Comment: It would work better if you updated the posted question, instead, so that everyone has a chance to chime in.